# Import a JSON file in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have JSON file that I want to access via the import statement.  I don't want to expose the name directly in the code but read the name from the .env file and import it.

Here is a snippet of my code that works from directly importing the file. How can I change it so that I can read the file name from .env and import the actual file

```
import keys from 'home/path/account.json';
class SecurityServices {
   getToken(){
     return keys.certs;
   }
}
```

basically I have the env file with the path and I was import it in my typescript code.

.env
{
"keyFile":"home/path/account.json'"
}

Thanks

Comment: What happens instead when you import it?

Comment: What does this have to do with TS specifically?

Comment: import fs from process.env.GC_FILE!;
-- error --String literal expected

Comment: You can't do this using a normal `import`; you'd have to do a dynamic `await import(process.env.GC_FILE);` if you have top-level await turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to replace a bit of text at build time, bundlers like rollup are the tool for you. For example:

```ts
// file.ts
import keys from 'home/path/account.json';

// rollup.config.js
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

export default {
  client: {
    plugins: [
      replace({ 'home/path/account.json': process.env.keyFile })
```

You should be able to accomplish something similar with webpack, gulp, and most other modern bundlers.

Alternatively (and my preference), consider doing a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_import). Note that this requires using `Promises` adding an async factor to your code:

```ts
let _loadedJson: any = null;

export async function getJsonFromFile() {
  if (_loadedJson === null) {
    // This dynamic import will happen one time, when this is first called.
    _loadedJson = await import(process.env.keyFile);
  }
  // Optionally assert a type at return since dynamic imports resolve to `any`.
  return _loadedJson as Record<string, any>
}
```

With this approach, you reduce the initial build size at the cost of needing to work with the JSON asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-reader

Load the properties from a file using that.  Put it in an object, import that object file and use the property.  For example

```
let PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
let properties = null;
try {
    debugLog('Looking for ' + os.homedir() + '/app.properties')
    properties = PropertiesReader(os.homedir() + '/app.properties');
    debugLog('Found ' + os.homedir() + '/app.properties')
} catch(e) {
    debugLog(os.homedir() + '/app.properties' + ' not found.  Using default properties')
}
```

then

```
const prop = properties.get(name);
```